# Debian Jessie - Where Did the "About Xfce" Desktop Menu Item Go?

Tags: linux, xfce

Just upgraded a netbook from Debian Wheezy to Jessie (yeah, I know...).

I use the Xfce4 desktop and noticed that the "About Xfce" desktop context menu item is missing under Jessie.

How do I get this back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I loaded the **libxfce4ui-utils** package - end of problem!